# On startup/shutdown lists of commands are shown on screen, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04

A list of commands are shown on startup/shutdown of Ubuntu (16.04).

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

How can I disable these commands from being displayed on startup/shutdown of the system?

Comment: what's the output of `grep LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub`?

Comment: Its GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="debug",  Ohh so debug mode has been enabled, due to which the whole execution is shown.

Comment: Yes that's right. I have debug params because I actually want to see all that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your boot parameters by editing the configuration file for GRUB:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

in the line that begins `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` remove `debug` and replace with `quiet` and `splash`, so the line reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Save and exit and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thanks. Recently I did changed the grub file, for some other issue and also kept the backup of grub file.

Comment: oh so you restored your backup? Nice work @Aparna :)